# Is there a blame/annotate for RCS on windows?

Tags: version-control, rcs

I am accessing some source code controlled in RCS on Windows.

How can I find out in which revision particular lines of source code were last changed? The feature is variously called 'blame' or 'annotate' depending on the VCS.

The http://blame.sourceforge.net/ project sounds like its Linux only.

Comment: In `git`, `bisect` is totally unrelated to `blame`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, updated question accordingly

Comment: Note that the [Blame on Sourceforge](http://blame.sourceforge.net/) page cited in the question is missing altogether.  There is a website for [RCS Blame](https://invisible-island.net/rcs-blame/rcs-blame.html) which notes that the Sourceforge page is missing but provides links to the code that was recovered from elsewhere.  It appears that the latest release as I type was version 1.3.1-20221108 — which means that the code is maintained.  It isn't immediately clear why the date-annotated versions (there's another from January 2022) were not designated 1.3.2 and 1.3.3.

Comment: There's also a related program `rcshist` available from the same site — [rcshist](https://invisible-island.net/rcshist/rcshist.html).  Be aware that that (as of 2023-01-09), the latest version of the code in the archives link is [rcshist-1.04.20221002.tgz](https://invisible-island.net/archives/rcshist/rcshist-1.04-20221002.tgz), but the [source](https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/rcshist.tar.gz) link on the 'home' page link to [rcshist-1.04-20190106.tgz](https://invisible-island.net/archives/rcshist/rcshist-1.04-20190106.tgz).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in functionality. As an alternative, here are some workarounds:

- [Emacs Version Control](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl)
- [Emacs RCS](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevisionControlSystem)
- [Tcl RCS](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/rcs.html)

Answer (score 2):

CVS and RCS use the same file format.

Install CVS, create an empty CVS repository, manually copy the RCS `*,v` file(s) into the CVS repository, and run `cvs annotate`.

See also this question: [How to install CVS in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15222318/827263).

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately 'MKS Source Integrity' does not use the standard 'RCS' file format.

Comment: @Sam: Hmm? You said the files were "controlled in RCS", and you used the RCS tag on the question.

Comment: Sorry. I originally thought 'MKS Source Integrity' was an implementation of RCS on Windows. It turns out to be a proprietary CMS, with not much in common with RCS.

Comment: Your original question (about a blame/annotate command for RCS) was potentially useful to others, and it got a couple of useful answers. I suggest you revert your question, removing references to MKS, and post your MKS question separately. Tagging the new question "mks-integrity" is likely to get some good answers. (I won't be able to answer it myself.)

Comment: Did as @Keith suggested - new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975996/is-there-a-blame-annotate-for-mks-source-integrity